# Installing codeigniter in a subfolder and point to the main site?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdirectory

I'm trying install my codeigniter application in a sub folder: `http://website.com/sub_folder`

And I want that this site is accessible through: `http://website.com/`

I have the following info in my `application/config.php` file for the base url: `$config['base_url']    = 'http://website.com/sub_folder';`

This is my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|assets|favicon\.gif|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub_folder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

The problem is that when I change the `$config['base_url']` to access my asset files, like css etc al my other links using `$base_url()` point to : `http://website.com/sub_folder` too instead of `http://website.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want to achieve, you're doing it wrong, simply place `index.php` file in your root folder and your application to the sub-folder.

Change `system` and `application` paths in `index.php` to where exactly they are located and you're done.

```
$system_path = 'subfolder/system';
$application_folder = 'subfolder/applications';
```

In any case, if it's possible, consider moving `application` and `system` folders out of the root directory as it will cover hundreds of potential security holes.

Comment: Yeah I know it's not the best set up but I have no other option here.
Those variables in my index folder were already changed though.